# How to organize this table so it can be accessible depending on the type of object accessing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

[image]

I have this table which contains a field called 'icon_for' which I have been using to check if the icon can be used for a 'User' or a 'Greeting'.

This is obviously not the best way to do this as if I want to use an icon for say both a 'Greeting' and a 'User' or even some other object I would be stuck.

Do I need to make another table called icons_object and then list the icon_id and object_name?
Seems like I would have to do a lot of repeating of the icon_id's if an icon is used for several objects but is this the way to go?

Also what would this table association in Rails be.  Say the Table is called icons_objects.
Then in Rails would it be

Icon.rb

icon has_many :icon_objects ?????

Totally confused here so any help for a NOOB would be appreciated.

Is there a way to do this normalized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use polymorphic associations.  For example:

```
class Icon < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :iconable, :polymorphic => true
end    

class Greeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icons, :as => :iconable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icons, :as => :iconable
end
```

Then you could get to icons from greetings or user:

```
@user.icons
@greeting.icons
@icon.iconable  #returns the parent type.
```

Or if you wanted to query icons for a particular type:

```
Icon.where(:iconable_type => "greeting")
```

This approach is not unlike the one you have already taken.  The benefits of doing this method is that you can get the parent object without worrying about what type it is, like you would if you tried to implement the other answer in this thread.

You will just need to run some migrations to get everything working properly.  You can see more information at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations.

Edit per comment:

Strictly speaking, you're correct.  You cannot have a polymorphic record which points to a User and a Greeting.  However, you can make a small change and create another model, which would kind of act like a join table.

```
class IconConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inconable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :icon
end

class Icon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icon_connections
end

class Greeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icon_connections, :as => :iconable
  has_many :icons, :through => :icon_connections
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :icon_connections, :as => :iconable
  has_many :icons, :through => :icon_connections
end
```

Each IconConnection would point to either a Greeting or a User, and each of the IconConnections would point to the same Icon.

This setup assumes that you can have multiple icons for each user and greeting, but if not, you can replace the `has_many`'s with `has_one`'s

Comment: Hi Sean, Thanks for the information. I am having some trouble getting my head around it.  What if I wanted the same icon to be accessible for the greeting and the user.  The way it looks on the guides is that one icon for one object.  I might have misunderstood though.  I want the same icon to be available for both greeting and user.  I am not sure I can do this with polymorphic. Am I wrong?

Comment: Wow that is great. Thanks very much for clearing that up and for the all the details. I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about a many-to-many relationship. As in icons can belong to more than one object and an object can have more than one icon. You need a matching table for that kind of relationship... something like icon_objects that you talked about. Then, your models you will use either a `has_many :through` relationship or `has_and_belongs_to_many`. If icon_objects only exists to map objects to icons then you probably want to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. If you think you'll need to store additional information about a specific icons relationship to a specific object, then you might need an actual `IconObject` model and should use `has_many :through` to map icons to objects.

**If an object can only have one icon** then put the foreign key in each of the object tables (so `users` has an `icon_id` field, and so does the `greetings` table). Then User and Greeting will have a `belongs_to` relationship with Icon, and Icon will have a `has_many` relationship with both User and Greeting.

Comment: Hi Cark,Thanks for the information. I think I will have to go this route because an icon can belong to both a greeting and a user. I don't need to store any additional information.  The objects can have only one icon so I already have those foreign keys in place and associations as you stated has_many and belongs_to. However I am confused about the join table. Do I make an icon_objects table and if so how does that get wired together so I can access the icons say for a user in @user.icons?